# Angularjs fetching fields

Tags: angularjs

I have an input form field within a div to get the client name, project start date, and project end date. However, I am getting those field values as undefined. My code is below. I have added code for getting those three fields:

```
var  cilentname=$scope.vm.clientname;
var prjstartdate=$scope.vm.prjstartdate ;
var prjenddate=$scope.vm.prjenddate;


<form name="form" ng-submit="vm.login()" role="form">
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="form-horizontal">
          <div class="form-group">

            <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Project Name</label>
            <div class="col-sm-9">
                <input type="text" name="prjname" id="prjname" class="form-control" ng-model="vm.prjname" required />
                <span ng-show="form.firstName.$dirty && form.firstName.$error.required" class="help-block">First name is required</span>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Client Name</label>
            <div class="col-sm-9">
                <div ng-controller="MyCntrl"  >
                    <select class="form-control"  name="clientname" id="clientname" class="form-control" ng-model="vm.clientname" ng-change="change(myColor)" >
                        <option value="">Select Client Name</option>                                
                        <option ng-repeat="color in colors" 
                                value="{{color.value}}" 
                                ng-selected="{{color.value == myColor}}" name="clientname" id="clientname" class="form-control" ng-model="vm.clientname">
                          {{color.clientname}}
                        </option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Project Status</label>
            <div class="col-sm-9">
                <input type="text" name="prjsta" id="prjsta" class="form-control" ng-model="vm.prjsta" required />
                <span ng-show="form.username.$dirty && form.username.$error.required" class="help-block">Username is required</span>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Project Startdate</label>
            <div class="col-sm-9">

            <!--   <input type="text" name="prjstartdate" id="prjstartdate" class="form-control" ng-model="vm.user.prjstartdate" required />-->
<div class="container" id="sandbox-container">
 <div class="input-daterange input-group" id="datepicker">
 <input class="input-sm form-control" name="prjstartdate" id="prjstartdate" class="form-control" ng-model="vm.prjstartdate"  type="text">

    </div>

</div>
                <span ng-show="form.password.$dirty && form.password.$error.required" class="help-block">Password is required</span>
            </div>
          </div>



            <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Project Enddate</label>
            <div class="col-sm-9">
                <!-- <input type="text" name="prjenddate" id="prjenddate" class="form-control" ng-model="vm.user.prjenddate" required />-->

                <div class="container" id="sandbox-container">
 <div class="input-daterange input-group" id="datepicker">
 <input class="input-sm form-control" name="prjenddate" id="prjenddate" class="form-control" ng-model="vm.prjenddate"  type="text">

    </div>

</div>
                <span ng-show="form.password.$dirty && form.password.$error.required" class="help-block">Password is required</span>
            </div>
          </div>

            <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Project PIN Url</label>
            <div class="col-sm-9">
                <input type="text" name="prjurl" id="prjurl" class="form-control" ng-model="vm.prjurl" required />
                <span ng-show="form.password.$dirty && form.password.$error.required" class="help-block">Password is required</span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

function MyCntrlsave($scope,$http) {

```
    $scope.savedetails = function() {
    var vm = this;
    var  projectname=$scope.vm.prjname;
    var  cilentname=vm.clientname
    var clientstatus=$scope.vm.prjsta
    var prjstartdate=$scope.vm.prjstartdate
    var prjenddate=$scope.vm.prjenddate
    var prjurl=$scope.vm.prjurl
    alert("cilentname"+cilentname)
    alert("prjstartdate"+prjstartdate)
    alert("prjenddate"+prjenddate)

    }
    }
```

Comment: I think you missed to add the code where you trying to get these fields.

Comment: function MyCntrlsave($scope,$http) {
    
  $scope.savedetails = function() {
     var vm = this;
     var  projectname=$scope.vm.prjname;
     var  cilentname=$scope.vm.clientname;
     var clientstatus=$scope.vm.prjsta
     var prjstartdate=$scope.vm.prjstartdate
     var prjenddate=$scope.vm.prjenddate
     var prjurl=$scope.vm.prjurl
  alert("cilentname"+cilentname)
  alert("prjstartdate"+prjstartdate)
  alert("prjenddate"+prjenddate)
  

  }
  }

Comment: pls look in to that i need solution pls

Comment: instead of ``$scope.vm.clientname``  use ``vm.clientname`` and check. Also instead of dumping your code in comments , update your question and format the code properly.

Comment: done the same but again i am getting undefined

Comment: @panduk: Did `controllerAs` work?

Answer (score 1):

If you use `var vm = this` you should also use `controllerAs` syntax. So at the point where you use `MyCntrlsave` you either use `MyCntrl as vm` (if using ng-ctrl in HTML) or `controllerAs` (if using something likes routes and views).

Answer (score 0):

You need to crate an empty object to hold you data. something like below

```
$scope.fromData = {};
```

Then in your html you need to include this object like this to hold data

```
<div class="form-group">

        <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Project Name</label>
        <div class="col-sm-9">
            <input type="text" name="prjname" id="prjname" class="form-control" ng-model="fromData.prjname" required />
            <span ng-show="form.firstName.$dirty && form.firstName.$error.required" class="help-block">First name is required</span>
        </div>
 </div>
```

Hope this helps